# How to set geocode custom field?

Tags: apex, geolocation

I know how to set the Lat/Lng on standard Geocoding fields, but let's say I have Geocode__c on a custom object.

Do I set the Lat/Lng by simply doing:

CustomObjectInstance.Geocode__c.Latitude__c = ;
CustomObjectInstance.Geocode__c.Longitude__c = ;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is pretty straightforward to get and set. Here is some [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=custom_field_geolocate_overview.htm) which offers the following two lines:

```
Double theLatitude = myObject__c.aLocation__latitude__s;
myObject__c.aLocation__longitude__s = theLongitude;
```